# Spring Router + Vue Router + SPA

Tags: spring, vue.js, single-page-application, router

I try create SPA via Vue.js and Spring Boot.
I want to synchronize Spring + Vue Routers so that when the page is refreshed, the state of the SPA is saved.

I need what entered url into the address bar (including parameters) opened SPA components witch state.

I managed to do it separately, but when the page is refreshed, the Spring route fires.

If we click on the SPA buttons, Vue Router fires. Else if when we open url in browser, Spring route fires and we see white page (500 error).

How to synchronize them?

Spring router

```
@Controller
public class SpaController {

    @RequestMapping("/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String forwardHome(){
        return "forward:/";
    }

}
```

Vue Router

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: AboutView
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    ...
  ]
})
```

Example: we have mainpage - localhost:8080 with header menu with /about, /home, /contact buttons...
Click button with url /about and we see about component SPA - Vue Router work and /about added in browser url

Refresh page - we see Error 500 - white page - is Spring route(?).
And if we open localhost:8080/about - we see same Error 500 - white page - is Spring route

I want to see the same thing when we refresh the page or open in  localhost:8080/about url.

Also i think maybe better need create purge Vue.js SPA client (without spring backend) and messaging via Axios with Spring Router which be like API gateway.
Example: client Vue.js <-> Spring REST <-> service
But i want use url from browser to open SPA components with states (localhost:8080/about?params=param) and i dont know that do it.

And i use vite, if i run **npm run dev** (dev front server
with hot reload at :5173 port), **all works** like i want - refresh, manual get request via url, SPA buttons. But how build prod project which work like this dev server?

I will be glad for any help